# Unable to fetch db data in proper format for PHP in_array()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've tried everything imaginable, but when I create an array dynamically from db values I can't seem to get it formatted properly to work with `in_array()`.  I believe that the problem is simply the need to encase each value in quotes, because I have no trouble using `in_array()` with a hard-coded array as long as it's formatted that way, but I haven't been able to add the quotes with either `explode` or `implode`.

*What I'm trying to do:* This is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to, which is to filter a query's result based on how well a product matches a list of customer preferences (no risk of injection, and I've tried doing it both with and without PDO's).

*I know that there are several very similar postings, but after spending more hours than I care to admit trying to implement every tutorial and posting I've seen, I decided it was time to turn to the community for help.*

**in_array() statement**

```
  $Color='Black';
  if (in_array($Color, $colors_love_Arrays)) {
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
}
```

**Query which forms array**

```
$colors_love_Array = array(); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM style WHERE style.user_id = $user_id") or die(mysql_error());    

while ($row_profile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
// I've tried both of these, both separately and together
$colors_love_Array[] = $row_profile['colors_love'];    
$colors_love_Array = explode('",', $row_profile['colors_love']);
```

}

**How I need to structure the array**

```
$colors_love_Array = array('Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray','White','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red');
```

**The result of `var_dump ($colors_love_Array);` is:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(59) "Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red " }
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 What makes you think that? I don't see any indicating it's a var type as opposed to an int type.

Comment: I didn't bother including the rest of the code, but it's declared at the beginning with the statement:  $user_id = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'];

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 - I hadn't realized that SO didn't like emoticons ;-) I was just smiling because it's a bit rare here to see people admitting an oversight so quickly and with such good humor :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation state for **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**:

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

But the var_dump clearly tells you that the nested value you want is a string.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(59) trim("Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red ") }
                 ^^^^^^
```

---

One possible way is to use **[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)** instead of **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**:

```
$Color='Black';
  if (strpos($Color, $colors_love_Arrays[0]) !== false) {
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
```

However it will match if you have colors like, lets say, `WeirdBlack`.

Indeed:

```
$Color='Black';
  if (strpos($Color, "WeirdBlack") !== false) {
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Matches: WeirdBlack;
```

---

Alternatively you want to use **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
$Color='Black';
  if (preg_match('/(?:^|,)('.$Color.')(?:,|$)/', "Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red ") !== false)
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
```

The regex used is `'/(?:^|,)('.$Color.')(?:,|$)/'`:

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ9dB8/1)**

---

You might want to get an array instead. Then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$arr = explode(',', trim($colors_love_Array[0]));
```

And then use it like this:

```
$Color='Black';
  if (in_array($Color, $arr)) {
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
}
```

Or use **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** again:

```
$Color = 'Black';
$arr = explode(',', trim("Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red "));
   if (preg_grep('/('.$Color.')/', $arr))
        echo 'match';
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why that's better? Also, is there no way to actually use in_array() with db values?

Comment: str_pos will search a string for the occurance of a string, e.g. 'bc' in 'abcde' will match true.

Comment: @KohjahBreese - Would you mind elaborating? I'm still not sure why that's better :-(

Comment: It isn't better. As you eloborate below, you want to get an array.

Comment: Adam - You're absolutely right :-) Can you show me how to structure it as an array instead of a string?

Comment: @ChayaCooper Did find the solution at your problem ?

Comment: Adam - That worked perfectly, and you really helped me understand some things that weren't clear in the documentation :-D Any chance that I can trouble you to show me how to use preg_match with a variable instead of a hard-coded array (so that I'll know how to use it ;-))?

Answer (score 1):

check this, i think it should work for you

> $colors_love_Array = array(); 
>   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM style WHERE style.user_id = $user_id") or die(mysql_error());
>
> while ($row_profile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
>        // I've tried both of these, both separately and together
>        $colors_love_Array[] = $row_profile['colors_love'];
>   }
>
> $newColorsArray = explode(",", implode($colors_love_Array));
>
> if(in_array($Color, $newColorsArray)){
>       echo "Matches: ".$Color;
>   }

Comment: You were definitely on the right track :-) The syntax was just a bit off on the explode statement, but Adam's suggestion of $arr = explode(',', trim($colors_love_Array[0])); did the trick :-)

Comment: there was a little error in the explode statement. i missed the comma for segregation of 2nd parameter and as the ##$colors_love_Array## is an array therefore it should be imploded to make that a variable.. now i have edited that. check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your result be an array, rather than a string separated by commas?

Anyway, with your result as var_dumped above.

```
$parts = explode( ',', trim( $colors_love_Array ) );
if( in_array( 'Black', $parts ) )
    echo "is here\n";
```

But I would imagine you actually want to get this:

```
"Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red"
```

as an array. Since I do not know what is in your DB, I cannot offer advice in that area.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I do want it as an array :-) But for it to work the values each seem to need to be encased in quotes (i.e. "'Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray'... )

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin or the mysql command line interface? If so, what is the result from: **SELECT * FROM style WHERE style.user_id = $user_id** where you replace $user_id with a real user_id?

Comment: The result of echo $row_profile['colors_love']; is  Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red

Comment: Do you know if that is stored as as string in one row, or is that list being created from multiple rows?

Comment: I'll actually need to use it in both situations, but this particular column is a string (it contains comma-separated values)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit wrong. The code is storing all of the colors as a string, although you receive them as an array. Therefore you need to use `strpos` to search through the string for a specific occurrence of another string - i.e. does the string contain `Black` anywhere. Using this approach will make your life quite harder if for example later you need to be able to sort the colors in a specific way.

As @Adam Sinclair suggested, because the data is contained as a `string`, you can use `preg_match` to  check if the string contains a color. Unfortunately `preg_match` is quite an expensive function and should be used wisely and as a last resort.

Also, I would suggest you use `PDO` and prepared statements for your connections to the database - you don't want SQL injections, right?

In my opinion, the better way of achieving your task is using code similar to the one below:

```
<?php    
// Host
$hostname = 'localhost';

// Database
$database = 'database';

// Username
$username = 'user';

// Password
$password = 'pass';

// Connection DSN.
// http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$database;

try {
    // Create a database connection using PDO
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    // The value of the user_id (i.e. $_SESSION['user_id'])
    $user_id = 1301;

    // Get all colors, liked by a specific user.
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM style WHERE style.user_id = :user_id');
    // Bind the value of $user_id to :user_id in the query.
    $query->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    // Execute the query
    $query->execute();

    // Gets all results for a specific database column (i.e. 'color_loves').
    // In my table, I had color_id, user_id, color_loves, therefore the desired index is 2.
    // NOTE: Remember array indexes start counting from 0.
    $colors = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 2);

    // The output of the above will be something similar to this:
    // array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Black" [1]=> string(8) "Charcoal" [2]=> string(10) "Light_Gray" [3]=> string(5) "White" [4]=> string(10) "Royal_Blue" }

    $color='Black';
    if (in_array($color, $colors)) {
        echo "Matches: ", $color;
    }
    // Outputs Matches: Black

    // Disconnect from the database.
    $db = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // Output any exception messages that might occur
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

As you can see - it's simple, clean, secured and extendable. No need of hard-to-read regex, exploding/imploding strings fron/to arrays and etc. And if in future, your task evolves and the colors need to be sorted, you can easily do that by readying the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).